# A widow using her deceased husbands semen to conceive?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, technology, pregnancy-birth, baby-infant

If a husband has some of his semen frozen/saved and then dies, what halachic and hashkafic issues have to be addressed when deciding if his widow is allowed to/can/should use that semen to become pregnant? Does anything change if the husband was a Cohen?

Comment: I know Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach addressed the halachic status of postmortem paternity. See these pdfs https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a410/ff8b210a68e72fa233cc9ff6dcc632080690.pdf  https://www.yutorah.org/download.cfm?materialID=532222 and mp3s: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/913676/ms-lauren-flicker-rabbi-dani-rapp/ethics-of-postmortem-reproduction/ https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/886901/rabbi-effie-kleinberg/fathering-a-child-after-death/ https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/838178/rabbi-dani-rapp/medical-ethics-1-postmortem-insemination/

Comment: Terumah.  Yibum.

Comment: Highly related, if not a duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27817/

Comment: First thoughts: is artificially inseminated, halachically considered filiation (for the father)?

Comment: @yO_ There is a Taz in Yoreh Deah (195:7) who says that if a woman sat down on a bed and became pregnant from someone's semen, the vlad is kasher because there's no bi'as isur. I recall hearing that one of the biggest poskim in E"Y now has used/uses this Taz to allow ivf in certain circumstances (but this should be taken with a grain of salt).